# Have successfully inserted the values but, how to insert with autoincrement?

Tags: mysql, servlets, jdbc

My database: [MYSQL SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laaOP.jpg)

I have inserted the values from HTML to the MySQL database. How can I use the insert command for autoincrement column?

Servlet code:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

@WebServlet(name = "Register")
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
static String username="root";
static String password="root";
static String dburl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conferencesystem";
static String mydriver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String Firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String Lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    int Mobilenumber = 
Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mobilenumber"));
    String Email = request.getParameter("emailid");
    String Pass = request.getParameter("password");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h3>Guest Details </h3>");
    out.println("" + Firstname);
    out.println("" + Lastname);
    out.println("" + Email);
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");

    int id = 1101;

    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(mydriver);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, username, password);
        String query = "INSERT INTO author values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        stmt.setInt(1,id);

        stmt.setString(2,Firstname);

        stmt.setString(3,Lastname);

        stmt.setInt(4,Mobilenumber);

        stmt.setString(5,Email);

        stmt.setString(6,Pass);
        out.println("Your Record has been successfully inserted");
        int res= stmt.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

```css
h3{
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 25pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:SlateBlue;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: underline
}

table{
    font-family: Calibri;
    color:white;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: SlateBlue;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid navy
}
table.inner{
    border: 0px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<html>
<head>
    <title> Author Registration Form </title>

</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/Register">
    <h3>AUTHOR REGISTRATION FORM</h3>


    <table align="center" cellpadding = "10">

        <!----- First Name ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
            <td>FIRST NAME</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" maxlength="30"/>
                (max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
            </td>

        </tr>

        <!----- Last Name ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
            <td>LAST NAME</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" maxlength="30"/>
                (max 30 characters a-z and A-Z)
            </td>
        </tr>


        <!----- Mobile Number ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
            <td>MOBILE NUMBER</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" maxlength="10" />
                (10 digit number)
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!----- Email Id ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
            <td>EMAIL ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="emailid" maxlength="100" /></td>
        </tr>


        <!----- Choose password ---------------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
            <td>PASSWORD</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <!----- Submit and Reset ------------------------------------------------->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: exception]

I'm trying to insert data from the form data, but it doesn't work. How can I fix it?

In this updated question, I have successfully fixed some problems in inserting the values, but how can I deal with the autoincrementing column?

Comment: Why are you shouting at us? Locate your caps lock key and switch it off, and try again.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't mean that

Comment: Please reduce your problem to an [mcve] and post the exception as text in your question. Don't post important textual information as images. But to give you a tip: your insert statement is incorrect, please read a basic tutorial on JDBC, and specifically on prepared statements on how to pass values to a statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks , i've fixed that now i have probelm to deal with autoincrementing column value

Comment: @MarkRotteveel plz suggest

Comment: Please stop shouting in your questions.

Comment: I've successfully solved it, Thanks anyway, but I'm not being rude in any sense. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Yes you are, using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which is rude.

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know about these things. Thank you for letting me know, from now onwards, i'll take care of it. Thanks once again. @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO author
 (firstname
 ,lastname
 ,mobilenumber
 ,email 
 , pass) values(?,?,?,?,?);
```

And remove id from the prepared strings

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my time !